# LUIS incorrectly gives error saying we have to migrate to an Azure authoring resource while we already use an authoring resource

Tags: azure-language-understanding

When trying to open the LUIS portal (luis.ai) we get the error `To continue using the LUIS portal, please migrate your apps to an Azure authoring resource`. We could use the portal this morning and everything was working fine. Then suddenly this error occurs and we can't open the portal anymore. It happens to our entire team. Even after refreshing or logging out and logging in again.

The thing is that we are already using an Azure authoring resource. We have always used an Azure authoring resource from the moment we started working with LUIS. So I'm fairly sure that this error is incorrect.

What is going on? What do we do? Does anyone else have this problem?

Comment: Update: throughout the day I refreshed the page a couple of times and the error disappeared after half a day. So it seems that this was a problem on Microsofts end. Let's hope that it won't happen again and lets also hope that MS will get better at communicating that there is a problem with one of their services.

Comment: You can create a support ticket to Microsoft and resolve this issue.